# unique file based on 2 line match

Tags: bash, sorting, uniq

I have a file that has lines like this. I'd like to uniq this where every unique item consists of the 2 lines. so since

```
bob
100
```

is here twice I would only print it the one time. Help please. thanks,

```
bob
100
bill
130
joe
123
bob
100
joe
120
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
printf "%s %s\n" $(< file) | sort -u | tr " " "\n"
```

Output:

```
bill
130
bob
100
joe
120
joe
123
```

---

With bash builtins:

```
declare -A a            # declare associative array
while read name; do read value; a[$name $value]=; done < file
printf "%s\n" ${!a[@]}  # print array keys
```

Output:

```
joe
120
joe
123
bob
100
bill
130
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR%2{l=$0}!(NR%2){seen[l"\n"$0]}END{for(i in seen)print i}' input
```

Let me explain the command in a multi-line version:

```
# On odd lines numbers store the current line in l.
# Note that line numbers starting at 1 in awk
NR%2     {l=$0}

# On even line numbers create an index in a associative array.
# The index is the last line plus the current line.
# Duplicates would simply overwrite themselves.
!(NR%2)  {seen[l"\n"$0]}

# After the last line of input has been processed iterate
# through the array and print the indexes
END      {for(i in seen)print i}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed`:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file | sort -u | tr ' ' '\n'
```

- `N`: read next line, and append to current line
- `;`: command separator
- `s/\n/ /`: replace eol with space